# count li in ul after ul adds li from ajax

Tags: jquery, count, html-lists

How can I count the number of li in a ul, after adding more li via `ajax`?

I tried `$("#mylist li").size()` but it does not count the newly added ones.

I know there is this option, `$(returnedHTML).find('li').length` but I want the total count of existing and newly added li

CODE:
html

```
<ul id="mylist">
   <li> item 1</li>
   <li> item 2</li>
</ul>
```

jquery:

```
function updateNotificationCount(){    
    var nCount=$("#mylist li").length;      
        $("#Counter").html(nCount);     
    }

 $(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../scripts/getNotifications.php",
        data: "",

        success: function (data) {

              $('#mylist').append(data);
              updateNotificationCount();


        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {alert("error");
            alert(xhr.statusText);
            alert(xhr.responseText);
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }

        });
});
```

I can get teh ul updated without problem. only the counting is in limbo

Comment: Please post a full code example.

Comment: I'm wondering if the function executes before the items are appended. You might want to test this by wrapping the call to the function in a setTimeout to go off after a second to check.

Comment: @aVC the code should work see http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/TVgc6/

Comment: @Musa you are right, it should work. I tried defining the whole counting function inside "success" and it works. I will check why it is not working as an outside function. I am sure its something silly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use  `$("#mylist li").length` after you add the `<li>`s with ajax.

Comment: tried it. called this on ajax success, but still shows the old count.

Comment: @aVC Did you try it **after** you added the `<li>`s to the list? also show your code.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
$( "#mylist li" ).ajaxComplete(function(){
  var nCount=$("#mylist li").length;      
  $("#Counter").html(nCount);
});
```

your `li` are added dynamically to the DOM so can try when your ajax call complete. you did call the `updateNotificationCount()` on success but if that does not seems to work then you can use `live()` or `delegate()` to handle the dynamic count.

Comment: thanks, with minor changes to @Musa 's answer, i got it working  and now i am on to find out what was I doing wrong. Thanks a lot!!